# Issue with DECLARE @CutOffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR), @NumberOfYears, @StartDate);

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, date, dimension

When executing the steps in this query. I am running into an issue with the

```
DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @NumberOfYears, @StartDate);
```

I get a message of Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable “”CutOffDate”.

Should I be adding something in this syntax? Meaning “year” should be defined? or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that you have defined the @StartDate and @NumberOfYears this works just fine.

```
DECLARE @NumberOfYears INT = 1 ,
    @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-11-01';

DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, @NumberOfYears, @StartDate);

SELECT  @CutoffDate;
```

Comment: In this case the error is the name. Here is my actual syntax:DECLARE (at)NumberOfyears INT = 30 , @StartDate DATETIME = '2010-01-01';

DECLARE (at)CustOffDate DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, (at)NumberOfYears, (at)StartDate);

SELECT (at)CutoffDate; (replaed at sign with (at). The comments here will not let me submit with 'at sign". But my syntax appears to be correct based on your above example

Comment: In your actual syntax posted your date variable is CustOffDate, and you are selecting CutoffDate. Typo with the extra s.

Comment: that was it. I'm a moron. I apologize. When removing the "s" I was able to move forward. I think the difference is that I moved on to executing other statements AFTER executing the numberof years etc. I think they need to be in sequence? Either way, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I notice a case-sensitive difference between your declaration `@CutoffDate`, and `@CutOffDate` from the error message.

Check to see if you're not using a case-sensitive collation.